# How can I convert a complex program flow into a stateless one for the Web?

Tags: multithreading, http, web, state

Let's say I have a simple single-player text based RPG that runs as a console application.
Over-simplified pseudocode:

```
... 
while (character.hp > 0 and monster.hp > 0)  
    console.write("Attack, Magic, Run?")  
    character.doAction(console.read())  
    monster.attack(character)  
... etc. ...
```

Now let's say I want to turn this into a multiplayer online game. In the server, I can have each client run in it's own thread, and the code won't change much:

```
...
while (character.hp > 0 and monster.hp > 0)  
    socket.send("Attack, Magic, Run?")  
    character.doAction(socket.receive())  
    monster.attack(character)  
... etc. ...
```

This works, but there are two problems:
- Having one thread per client is generally not recommended because it scales poorly.
- Writing a custom socket server and client is a pain.

So having the game run on a web server solves both of those problems, but it introduces a new one: The web is inherently stateless. As far as I can tell, I would have to convert the threaded program flow into a state machine, pull the state from a database at the start of each request, and then store the modified state in the database at the end of the request handler.  This seems even more painful than writing a custom socket server.  So my question is, is there any non-painful way to achieve this? Ideally, there would be a solution that would allow me to keep the simple pseudocode from above mostly unchanged.  I am open to suggestions in all languages and/or platforms.

Comment: I selected the code and clicked the curly braces for you.

Comment: Note that there are only two states to the state machine and only one event. The states are 'waiting' and 'done' and the event is 'incoming request'. Maybe this isn't as hard as you imagine. Think about rearranging your loop so the send() is at the bottom and the 'doAction()' at the top. Some if's make it skip the top part the first time or if the request doesn't do anything interesting.

Comment: Yes, for that specific example, it isn't too hard. But that was just an oversimplified example, and as you can imagine, as the program flow becomes more complex, it becomes more difficult.

Comment: The alternative is to write the front end code in some language and have it talk to the back end via service calls to get information about the environment. The loop runs on the user's machine. If you use a browser its javascript. Then it phones home to have things happen and shows the results.

Comment: Who says having one thread per client scales poorly?  It's fine for at least several hundred clients.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the REST approach.  Each "state" your player can be in is actually a URL, and taking an action navigates to a new URL.  Your "socket.send()" becomes returning a webpage, and "socket.receive()" is just handling the request.

So say your toon starts in "room A".  They are viewing the webpage `http://game.example.com/room-a/` which has the html code

```
You see a monster here.  Do you
<a href="attack">Attack</a>,
<a href="magic">Magic</a>, or
<a href="run">Run</a>?
```

then you have three new pages:

room-a/attack:

```
The monster hits you.  You hit back!
Do you
<a href="attack">Attack</a>,
<a href="magic">Magic</a>, or
<a href="run">Run</a>?
```

room-a/magic:

```
The monster hits you.  You cast Magic Missile at the monster.   It hits!
Do you
<a href="attack">Attack</a>,
<a href="magic">Magic</a>, or
<a href="run">Run</a>?
```

room-a/run:

```
The monster hits you.  You run away!
Do you
<a href="rest">Rest</a>,
<a href="search">Search</a>, or
<a href="/room-b/">Go back to Room B</a>?
```

You'll probably want to generate the pages by a program rather than statically of course, but you could get pretty far just having "static" pages too.  See [Addventure](http://addventure.com/cgi-bin/read.pl/addventure/game2/game2.db4/page/1.html) for an example of what you could do.

Comment: This is interesting. But I have a concern: at any one time, it is only valid for the client to be viewing _one_ of these pages, and the server needs to be in control of that. For example, the client should not be able to repeatedly visit the /room-a/level-up/ page. (In a multiplayer game, you can't make the assumption that the client is well-behaved.) So with that in mind, do you still think the REST approach is a good idea?

Comment: Sounds like this is the "active messages" concept: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Active_message